# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystruct.models.utils'

Tags: python-3.x, crf

i wants to use linearchain crf using pystruct library in pycharm, but i found this error

File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/sequential-rumour-detection/run.linearcrf.py", line 25, in 
    from pystruct.models import ChainCRF

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pystruct\models__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from .crf import CRF

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pystruct\models\crf.py", line 5, in 
    from .utils import loss_augment_unaries

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystruct.models.utils'

Please suggest me solution to solve this error. my python version is 3.7

Answer (score -1):

The issue is because you haven't installed pystruct. You need to install pystruct.

You can check this link [to install pystruct](https://pystruct.github.io/installation.html)